# Is it possible to extract wep iv fields with Scapy

Tags: scapy

Is it possible to write a Query with Scapy ? What i want is to extract all iv from all paquets of a pcap file. I do not want to filter packets, i also want to extract IV information and i need to extract ssid in the same time because there are multiple ap

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the IV part you could do:

```
import binascii
from scapy.all import *

    for pkt in PcapReader('myfile.cap'):
        try:
          if (pkt[1].iv):
            print(binascii.hexlify(pkt[1].iv))                  

        except:
            pass
```